# Set of positive integers that is closed with respect to multiplication by some set of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, integers

Is there a term for a set of positive integers that is closed with respect to multiplication by any element of some fixed set of primes?

## Example 1

Let $S$ denote the set of multiples of 5 that are divisible by at least one of 7 or 13, but not divisible by 19. Then, for any $m\in S$, 7$m$ and $13m$ are also contained in $S$.

## Example 2

Let $S'$ denote the set of positive integers that are divisible by at least one prime from each of the following sets: $\{5,7\},\{13,19\}, \{23, 31\}$ but not divisible by any prime in the set $\{101, 103\}$

Comment: The numbers in your example will have the form $5 \times a \times 7^m \times 13^n$ for non-negative integers $a, m, n$, where $a$ is not a multiple of $19$ and $m+n\ge1$.

Comment: This is true, but I'm more looking for a search term that will lead to related papers. What I'm interested in is learning about any results about such sets that are out there.

Comment: They are cosets in quotient monoids.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing one of these examples constructed as a quotient monoid.  Would it be possible to be more specific about what type of monoid? The monoid needs to be commutative at least, right?